# Stripe Card id using token in Android

Tags: java, android, token, credit-card, stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe Payment module in my application. In that I use this [Stripe Library.](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/tree/master/stripe)
Now using this code I generating token. Using this token I need **card `id`** **`before payment`**.

**`How to get this card id'. ?`**

Here I show you response of Stripe.

When I enter Card Information about the card Like this :

```
Stripe_Token::create(array(
"card" => array(
"number" => "4242424242424242",
"exp_month" => 8,
"exp_year" => 2015,
"cvc" => "314"
)
));
```

After that Stripe give me this response :

```
{
"id": "tok_14WdJ02eZvKYlo2CyaZ49ZP7",
"livemode": false,
"created": 1409272314,
"used": false,
"object": "token",
"type": "card",
"card": {
"id": "card_14WdJ02eZvKYlo2C5nE5XjtP",
"object": "card",
"last4": "4242",
"brand": "Visa",
"funding": "credit",
"exp_month": 8,
"exp_year": 2015,
"fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
"country": "US",
"name": null,
"address_line1": null,
"address_line2": null,
"address_city": null,
"address_state": null,
"address_zip": null,
"address_country": null,
"customer": null
}
}
```

**Before payment and after token created
I need this card id :**

```
"card": {
"id": "card_14WdJ02eZvKYlo2C5nE5XjtP",
}
```

Hope you get my question.

Comment: This is in Java right?

Comment: ya you can say that but i am using in android @MattR

Comment: @strider, i'm doing the same, i have one doubt, after getting the token where payment will be done, either from client side or server side

Comment: you can do at both side.. if you use card id then you can made payment at server side and if you use token then payment was done from your side...@Androidcuckoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Generating token 
Use this...

```
Customer.all(new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

Using this finally i got Cardid which i want.

Here is the total response of Customer.

```
{
  "data": [
    com.stripe.model.Customer JSON: {
      "object": "customer",
      "created": 1410001523,
      "id": "cus_4j9JlwfZ5arO4M",
      "livemode": false,
      "description": null,
      "email": "customer@example.com",
      "delinquent": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "subscriptions": {
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 0,
        "has_more": false,
        "url": "/v1/customers/cus_4j9JlwfZ5arO4M/subscriptions",
        "data": [

        ]
      },
      "discount": null,
      "account_balance": 0,
      "currency": "usd",
      "cards": {
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 1,
        "has_more": false,
        "url": "/v1/customers/cus_4j9JlwfZ5arO4M/cards",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "card_14Zh0M2eZvKYlo2CAl9gQ262",
            "object": "card",
            "last4": "4242",
            "brand": "Visa",
            "funding": "credit",
            "exp_month": 12,
            "exp_year": 2015,
            "fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
            "country": "US",
            "name": "akinci_yasin@hotmail.com",
            "address_line1": null,
            "address_line2": null,
            "address_city": null,
            "address_state": null,
            "address_zip": null,
            "address_country": null,
            "cvc_check": null,
            "address_line1_check": null,
            "address_zip_check": null,
            "customer": "cus_4j9JlwfZ5arO4M"
          }
        ]
      },
      "default_card": "card_14Zh0M2eZvKYlo2CAl9gQ262"
    },
    #<com.stripe.model.Customer[...] ...>,
    #<com.stripe.model.Customer[...] ...>
  ],
  "has_more": false
}
```

Hope it may help for You.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the response from stripe, you can simple get your card id and all other fields from the token object you get in response as follows:

```
String card_id = token.getCard().getId(); // to get card id
String id = token.getId(); // to get this "id": "tok_14WdJ02eZvKYlo2CyaZ49ZP7"
boolean live_mode = token.getLivemode(); // to get livemode
String last_four = token.getCard().getLast4(); // to get last 4
```

where **token** is the response object.

Answer (score 1):

[Using gson:](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/)

```
package gson.sample.one;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class gsonsample
{ 
    public class card {
        public String id;
        public String object;
        public String last4;
        public String brand;
        public String funding;
        public int exp_month;
        public int exp_year;
        public String fingerprint;
        public String country;
        public String name;
        public String address_line1;
        public String address_line2;
        public String address_city;
        public String address_state;
        public String address_zip;
        public String address_country;
        public String customer;
    }

    public class Response {
        public String id;
        public Boolean livemode;
        public int created;
        public String object;
        public String type;
        public card card;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String json = "{ \"id\": \"tok_14WdJ02eZvKYlo2CyaZ49ZP7\", \"livemode\": false, \"created\": 1409272314, \"used\": false, \"object\": \"token\", \"type\": \"card\", \"card\": { \"id\": \"card_14WdJ02eZvKYlo2C5nE5XjtP\", \"object\": \"card\", \"last4\": \"4242\", \"brand\": \"Visa\", \"funding\": \"credit\", \"exp_month\": 8, \"exp_year\": 2015, \"fingerprint\": \"Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c\", \"country\": \"US\", \"name\": null, \"address_line1\": null, \"address_line2\": null, \"address_city\": null, \"address_state\": null, \"address_zip\": null, \"address_country\": null, \"customer\": null } }"; 
        // 
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Response response = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);

        String id = response.card.id;

        System.out.println(id);
    }
}
```

Stripe also has these objects defined in the model definitions of their [Java API](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model) and usage examples in their [unit tests](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/stripe/StripeTest.java).